# Ubuntu: Mediakeys Configuration confusion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, media-keys

How does one configure the Mediakeys (for volume) under Ubuntu?

Everytime I touch something on the audio side (change mixer for Skype to work correctly etc), the Mediakeys related to the volume control somehow get "disconnected" from the volume control.

Help!

**Update**: I got rid of PulseAudio entirely and it seems my whole setup is much simpler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are experiencing this with Karmic, aren't you? The point is that Karmic has changed a lot of things in its pulse audio configuration and you cannot anymore choose from GUI what channels to control your media keys.

The solution depends from your hardware, but you can *most probably* fix this by:

- Opening `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf` and tweak it in order to ignore the channels you do not want to touch (in my case I wanted the media keys to only govern the PCM, so I had to exclude LFE and Master). To ignore a channel you have to set it with `volume = ignore`.
- Run `alsamixer` in a terminal, and set the channels you just ignored to 100%.

Hope this solves the problem for you (or at least help you to find the solution!)

Comment: I am still on Jaunty on my main machine...

Comment: Although this doesn't provide an answer to my problem and considering I have found a "solution", I'll approve it anyways.